# Global exception handler for basic spring application

Tags: java, spring, exception

I have a spring application, which is mainly used for task schedule purposes. Now I want a mechanism(say,Global Exception Handling) that handles all the exception within all tasks. Keep in mind that the application is not a web application, hence the `@ControllerAdvice` or `@ExceptionHandler` may not be applicable.

Comment: AFAIK there's no such mechanism, but maybe you could wrap all your tasks  with some `try-catch`

Comment: so I prefer to name it as a shortcoming for great spring framework.

Answer (score 1):

For scheduled task(s) custom error handler (*which implements [`ErrorHandler`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/ErrorHandler.html)*) can be registered as below

```
@Bean
public Executor taskScheduler() {       
    ThreadPoolTaskScheduler scheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
    scheduler.setErrorHandler(errorHandler());
    // set other properties
    return scheduler;
}

@Bean
public ErrorHandler errorHandler(){
    return new CustomErrorHandler();
}
```

Note that the `CustomErrorHandler` implements the `org.springframework.util.ErrorHandler`